# Using Susy SASS-framework w/ multiple partial files

Tags: sass, susy-sass

I'm using the Susy SASS-library. I'm compiling one main SASS-file that @imports various partial SASS-files. Inside the partials I use Susy-mixins. Do I need to @import "Susy" for every single partial SASS-file? What's the smart way to do this?

Comment: Did you try it with and without?  Seems like that would have given you your answer.

Comment: I've been experimenting with the best way to do this before asking this question. I'm not sure why it didn't work for me at first, maybe because I forgot to include the $susy configuration variable. @allejo's answer cleared up any confusion I had. Imported mixins and variables appear to be available across partials.

Comment: When you have an error, you need to be providing that error.  Otherwise it just looks like you have an exceptionally lazy question where you didn't bother trying anything.

Comment: True, that. I guess I could have phrased my question differently to not come across as lazy. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just have a single `@import "Susy"` before you import all of your other partials. As long as your main file imports Susy first, your partials will be able access it.

```
@import "Susy";

@import "partials/header";
@import "partials/footer";
```